# Can you do conventions-based binding with StructureMap 2.5.3?

Tags: inversion-of-control, structuremap, ninject

I find one of the best features of Ninject is conventions-based binding. eg.

```
Bind<IConfigurationSource>().To<RemoteConfigurationSource>()
.Only(When.Context.Target.Name.BeginsWith("remote"));

Bind<IConfigurationSource>().To<LocalConfigurationSource>()
.Only(When.Context.Target.Name.BeginsWith("local"));
```

http://ninject.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Conventions-Based%20Binding&referringTitle=Home

Is this possible in StructureMap 2.5.3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StructureMap has various ways of dynamically determining which concrete type to return based on a request (TheDefault.Is.ConstructedBy, TheDefault.Is.Conditional, etc).

However, (as of 2.5) none of them have access to the parameter name that is being filled, as in your example.